# Contract A delegatecall function in contract B which calls function in contract c. msg.sender for function in contract c?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, erc-721, delegatecall, proxy-contracts

If Function in **contract A** `delegatecall` function in **contract B** which calls function in **contract C**. What will be the `msg.sender` for function in **contract C**?

Answer (score 0):

The `msg.sender` according to the test scenario below is **Contract A**

The Change to state happens in Contract A and Contract C

For me it make sense because contract B has nothing to do with the transaction except running the logic. However, you need to verify the result by your own and use it on your own risk (I could be wrong or missed some edge cases!)

```
pragma solidity 0.8.12;

contract StorageA {
  uint public val = 1;
  event Test(string class,  address sender);
  constructor()  { }

  function setValue(uint v, address storageB, address storageC) external {
      emit Test("Contract Storage A", msg.sender);
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = storageB.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("setValue(uint256,address)", v, storageC));
        require(success == true);
  }
}

contract StorageB {
  uint public val = 2;
  event Test(string class,  address sender);
  constructor()  { }

  function setValue(uint v, address storageC) external { 
    emit Test("Contract Storage B", msg.sender);
    storageC.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("setValue(uint256)", v));
    val = v + 9;
  }
}

contract StorageC {
  uint public val = 3;
  event Test(string class,  address sender);
  constructor()  { }
  function setValue(uint v) external {
    emit Test("Contract Storage C", msg.sender);
    val = v + 7;
  }
}
```

Deploying **Contract A** at `0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138` with `val = 1`

Deploying **Contract B** at `0xd8b934580fcE35a11B58C6D73aDeE468a2833fa8` with `val = 2`

Deploying **Contract C** at `0xf8e81D47203A594245E36C48e151709F0C19fBe8` with `val = 3`

Now calling the method in Contract A like this:

[image]

It will give you the following events

[image]

The val values is changed as the following

[image]